# How do I set the release version in dnf?

Tags: dnf, version

I have the following warning when using `dnf`.

```js
No se pudo detectar la versión de lanzamiento (use '--releasever' para especificarla)
```

Which in English would be:

```js
Could not detect release version (use '--releasever' to specify it)
```

I want to be able to configure the release version so that that warning doesn't appear anymore.

Preferably I want to configure it so that it recognizes it as *OpenMandriva Cooker* or *CentOS 7*, but any configuration is useful to me, it is just so that the message does not appear.

Comment: OK, this needs much more context: on what platform are you using dnf, to which purpose, so you get this warning? We can't tell you how to configure dnf correctly without knowing on what, specifically. You can't just "configure something" and then hope things still work.

Comment: For example, CentOS 7 predates DNF; not sure you *could* productively use it on that platform.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was able to fix it, I did something but I don't remember exactly what I was able to change in the settings. I am with PuppyLinux LxSc64 with a PC from 2006 because I can't buy another one. The purpose is to fix the Nouveau video drivers, which I can't do at the moment because I don't have a fairly normal working package manager for Puppy Linux. When I finish installing Mesa I will be able to play Warzone 2100.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve it change the `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` file like this:

```bash
[cooker]
baseurl=https://abf-downloads.openmandriva.org/cooker/repository/x86_64/main/release/
installonly_limit=3
best=True
skip_if_unavailable=True
clean_requirements_on_remove=0
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```